# Split a string in C++ after a space, if more than 1 space leave it in the string

Tags: c++

I need to split a string by single spaces and store it into an array of strings. I can achieve this using the fonction boost:split, but what I am not being able to achieve is this:

If there is more than one space, I want to integrate the space in the vector

For example:
(underscore denotes space)

```
This_is_a_string. gets split into: A[0]=This A[1]=is A[2]=a A[3]=string.

This__is_a_string. gets split into: A[0]=This A[1] =_is A[2]=a A[4]=string.
```

How can I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: it's a strange request: implicitly you're saying that you want separators when no tokens were parsed - i.e. there are no empty tokens, a token always requires at least one character... that's unconventional. you'll probably have to write that functionality yourself.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/regex_token_iterator.html

Comment: Just write a loop going over the string. Study the memberfunctions that `std::string` provides. There are quite a few of them, getting an overview should help you for picking the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use a combination of the `find` and `substr` functions for string parsing.

Suppose there was just a single space everywhere, then the code would be:

```
while (str.find(" ") != string::npos)
{
  string temp = str.substr(0,str.find(" "));
  ans.push_back(temp);
  str = str.substr(str.find(" ")+1);
}
```

The additional request you have raised suggests that we call the `find` function after we are sure that it is not looking at leading spaces. For this, we can iterate over the leading spaces to count how many there are, and then call the `find` function to search from thereon. To use the `find` function from say after `x` positions (because there are x leading spaces), the call would be `str.find(" ",x)`.

You should also take care of corner cases such as when the entire string is composed of spaces at any point. In that case the `while` condition in the current form will not terminate. Add the `x` parameter there as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the most elegant solution, but it will get the job done:

```
void bizarre_string_split(const std::string& input, 
    std::vector<std::string>& output)
{
    std::size_t begin_break = 0;
    std::size_t end_break = 0;

    // count how many spaces we need to add onto the start of the next substring
    std::size_t append = 0;

    while (end_break != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string temp;
        end_break = input.find(' ', begin_break);
        temp = input.substr(begin_break, end_break - begin_break);
        // if the string is empty it is because end_break == begin_break
        // this happens because the first char of the substring is whitespace
        if (!temp.empty())
        {
            std::string temp2;
            while (append)
            {
                temp2 += ' ';
                --append;
            }
            temp2 += temp;
            output.push_back(temp2);
        }
        else
        {
            ++append;
        }
        begin_break = end_break + 1;
    }
}
```